# VMware Tools in Fusion 7

Tags: vmware

I'm new to Ubuntu (in fact to Linux) having come from a purely Windows environment. I've installed Ubuntu 14 on VMware - can someone tell me how to install VMware tools please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can get full documentation from http://partnerweb.vmware.com/GOSIG/Ubuntu_14_04.html:

#### Add the vmhgfs Driver

If you are using the interactive file drag-and-drop feature in VMware Workstation and Fusion, install the vmhgfs driver in the virtual machine. This driver is not included inbox in the operating system. Installing the additional vmhgfs driver does not disturb the other inbox VMware drivers or Open VMware Tools. To install this driver:

- Install Open VMware Tools.
- Install the traditional TAR Format VMware Tools that is bundled with
  VMware Workstation or Fusion products.

#### Add the deployPkg Tools Plug-in

If you are using the virtual machine as a template or if it will be protected by SRM (Site Recovery Manager), then install the deployPkg Tools plug-in. To install this plug-in:

- Obtain and import the VMware Packaging Public Keys:

  - Create a directory on your Ubuntu virtual machine to store the VMware
    Packaging Public Keys.
  - Download all the VMware Public Packaging Public Key files from the
    http://packages.vmware.com/tools/keys directory.
  - Save the files to the directory you created.
  - For each key that you download, import the key:

    ```
    $ sudo apt-key add /key_path/key_name
    ```

    key_path is the directory in which you saved the keys.
    key_name is the file name of a key.
- Create a file, /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vmware-tools.list, with the
  following content:

  deb http://packages.vmware.com/packages/ubuntu ubuntu_version main

ubuntu_version is either precise or trusty.

- Install the package:

  ```
  $ apt-get update
  $ apt-get install open-vm-tools-deploypkg
  ```

<sub>All rights go the owner from the above link</sub>